# Why can't I print the result of reduce/inject directly

Tags: ruby, mri

Found an interesting quirk in the ruby interpreter - at least in MRI 2.4.2.

As far as I can tell, each of the below code snippets *should* print '123'. If I try to print the result of reduce directly, I get `NoMethodError: undefined method '' for 1:Integer` (or whatever type the array contains) But if I first save the result and then print it, it works fine..

So, this code is broken:

```
puts [1,2,3].reduce('') do |memo, num|
  memo + num.to_s
end
```

And this code works:

```
temp = [1,2,3].reduce('') do |memo, num|
  memo + num.to_s
end
puts temp
```

These should work exactly the same, right? Should this be filed as a bug? Am I just missing something fundamental here?

I'd think it should at least show which method is trying to be called. Can't find anything in google about an undefined method without a method name...

Comment: Does the second code snippet work? I am getting `nil`, not sure if that is what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes. temp is successfully set to '123', and puts prints it normally (which also returns nil, is that what you're seeing?)

Updated question for clarity

Comment: This has been asked numerous times already. You are passing the block to `puts`, not to `inject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need parenthesis on the `puts` call. This works:

```
puts([1,2,3].reduce('') do |memo, num|
  memo + num.to_s
end)
```

Normally you can avoid parenthesis, but sometimes the parser will find ambiguities and will just raise an error, like in your first case.

Comment: Thanks! I guess i can see how it would be ambiguous if puts accepted a block, and reduce didn't require one in this case.

Just to be clear, generally, parens are always needed if there should be a block inside the function call?

Comment: @kennycoc I think so, yeah.